# TTN_NEEDTEXTW receives twice for one tooltip popup

Tags: c++, winapi, tooltip

There is a subclassing button in my program:

```
Fhwnd = CreateWindowExW(NULL, L"Button", NULL, WS_CHILD | WS_VISIBLE | BS_PUSHBUTTON | BS_OWNERDRAW, X, Y, Width, Height, parentHwnd, (HMENU)ID, 0, 0);
SetWindowSubclass(Fhwnd, &MyButtonSubclassProc, 0, (DWORD_PTR)this);
```

I add a tooltip for this button with `LPSTR_TEXTCALLBACKW` value:

```
toolInfo.lpszText = LPSTR_TEXTCALLBACKW;
```

And I noticed that when the tooltip popups, `OutputDebugString()` is printed **twice** (i.e. TTN_NEEDTEXTW occurs twice):

```
case WM_NOTIFY:
{
    switch(((LPNMHDR)lParam)->code)
    {
        case TTN_NEEDTEXTW:
        {
        NMTTDISPINFOW *pTT = (NMTTDISPINFOW*)lParam;

            if(pTT->uFlags && TTF_IDISHWND)
            {
            pTT->lpszText = FTooltipText;
            OutputDebugStringW(L"TTN_NEEDTEXTW\r\n");
            break;
            }
        break;
        }
    }
break;
}
```

I want to ask - is this normal?

**Update:**
Even if I set up a tooltip for the main window, TTN_NEEDTEXTW occurs twice as well.

```
case WM_CREATE:
{
HWND FTooltipHwnd = CreateWindowExW(NULL, TOOLTIPS_CLASS, NULL,
                                          WS_POPUP |TTS_ALWAYSTIP,
                                          CW_USEDEFAULT, CW_USEDEFAULT,
                                          CW_USEDEFAULT, CW_USEDEFAULT,
                                          hWnd, NULL, 
                                          hInst, NULL);

    if(FTooltipHwnd)
    {
    TOOLINFOW toolInfo = {0};
    toolInfo.cbSize = sizeof(TOOLINFOW);
    toolInfo.hwnd = hWnd;
    toolInfo.uFlags = TTF_IDISHWND | TTF_SUBCLASS;
    toolInfo.uId = (UINT_PTR)hWnd;
    toolInfo.lpszText = LPSTR_TEXTCALLBACKW;
    BOOL res = SendMessageW(FTooltipHwnd, TTM_ADDTOOLW, 0, (LPARAM)&toolInfo);
    }
}
```

It seems like normal. Is not it?

Comment: unclear for what you subclass button. can assume that this button is child window for your window. and you can specify self as window that receives the `TTN_GETDISPINFO` notification messages

Comment: @RbMm, I set up a tooltip for the main window and TTN_NEEDTEXTW occurs twice also (see edited code).

Comment: Can you provide us with a minimal case to reproduce the problem?Thanks.

Comment: @ZhuSong what did you mean? All source code I provided in question.

Comment: @lg_M You provided most of the code, but it does not seem to be a complete sample, and it seems that there are some codes that I do not understand like "SendMessageW(FTooltipHwnd, TTM_ADDTOOLW, 0, LPARAM)&toolInfo);". So I hope you can directly give a sample that can reproduce the problem to help us understand your problem.

Comment: @ZhuSong there is no more tooltip adding code in my project. You really don't understand what is SendMessage()??? If you want to help, can you just copy my code from the last two blocks (WM_CREATE and WM_NOTIFY) and paste it into a new project and check how many times the OutputDebugStringW prints?

Comment: @lg_M I just don't understand the parameter "LPARAM)&toolInfo", do you have one more or one less parenthesis?

Comment: @ZhuSong sorry, this is just a typo, I corrected it. The question remains the same.